# how to track objects within the ROI using dlib?

Tags: opencv, c++11, object, tracking, dlib

I'm trying to get the stream and defining the ROI and tracking an object within ROI using dlib correlation tracker but there is a error in compilation, not found any code or explanation which can describe any solution of this error. Thanks in advance.

cvcap.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "dlib/image_processing.h"
#include "dlib/gui_widgets.h"
#include "dlib/image_io.h"
#include "dlib/dir_nav.h"

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    CvCapture* camera = cvCaptureFromFile(argv[1]);

    if (camera==NULL)
        printf("camera is null\n");
    else
        printf("camera is not null\n");

    cvNamedWindow("CvCapture");
    while (cvWaitKey(1000)!=atoi("q")){
        double t1 = (double)cvGetTickCount();
        IplImage *img = cvQueryFrame(camera);

        cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(140, 150, 340, 150));

        IplImage *img1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), img->depth, img->nChannels);
        cvCopy(img, img1, NULL);
        cvResetImageROI(img);

        cvShowImage("ROI",img1);

        correlation_tracker tracker;
        tracker.start_track(img1, centered_rect(point(120,100), 80, 150));

        image_window win;
        tracker.update(img1);

        win.set_image(img1); 
        win.clear_overlay(); 
        win.add_overlay(tracker.get_position());

        cout << "hit enter to process next frame" << endl;
        cin.get();

        double t2=(double)cvGetTickCount();
        printf("time: %gms  fps: %.2g\n",(t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.), 1000./((t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.)));
        cvShowImage("CvCapture",img1);
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
}
```

the error is :

```
In file included from dlib/image_processing.h:24:0,
                 from cvcap.cpp:3:
dlib/image_processing/correlation_tracker.h: In instantiation of ‘dlib::point_transform_affine dlib::correlation_tracker::make_chip(const image_type&, 
dlib::drectangle, std::vector<dlib::matrix<std::complex<double> > >&) const [with image_type = _IplImage*]’:
dlib/image_processing/correlation_tracker.h:65:47:   required from ‘void dlib::correlation_tracker::start_track(const image_type&, const dlib::drectang
le&) [with image_type = _IplImage*]’
cvcap.cpp:36:70:   required from here
dlib/image_processing/correlation_tracker.h:301:67: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct dlib::image_traits<_IplImage*>’
             typedef typename image_traits<image_type>::pixel_type pixel_type;
```

**Update**

i edited my code and now it is compiling but when i'm running my code, tracking box appears but it is not tracking the objects.

```
for(;;) {
        if(!vcap.read(image)) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            break;
        } else {
        std::cout << "Starting" << std::endl;
            array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
            assign_image(img, cv_image<rgb_pixel>(image));

            tracker.start_track(img, centered_rect(point(413,260), 98, 126));

            for (unsigned long i = 0; i < img.size(); i++) {
                tracker.update(img);
                win.set_image(img); 
                win.clear_overlay(); 
                win.add_overlay(tracker.get_position());
            }
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an IplImage to the dlib routine. But if you look at the [docs](http://dlib.net/imaging.html#cv_image) it says you have to convert your opencv images to cv_images before passing them to dlib functions. And you can see this with the error pointing out IplImage doesn't have a pixel_type trait. A fix would be.

```
IplImage *img1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), img->depth, img->nChannels);
...
correlation_tracker tracker;
// Not sure if  the tracker wants a single channel image
// change rgb_alpha_pixel to uchar in that case.
tracker.start_track(dlib::cv_image<dlib::rgb_alpha_pixel>(img1), centered_rect(point(120,100), 80, 150));
```

[Pixel types](http://dlib.net/dlib/pixel.h.html#rgb_alpha_pixel) and the [Correlation tracker](http://dlib.net/dlib/image_processing/correlation_tracker_abstract.h.html#correlation_tracker)

EDIT: Passed your stuff to opencv 3 and this is compiling for me. Do you really need to use opencv 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "dlib/image_processing.h"
#include "dlib/gui_widgets.h"
#include "dlib/image_io.h"
#include "dlib/dir_nav.h"
#include <dlib/opencv/cv_image.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat frame;
    while (cap.read(frame)) {
        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        cv_image<unsigned char> img(frame);
        correlation_tracker tracker;
        tracker.start_track(img, centered_rect(point(120,100), 80, 150));

        image_window win;
        tracker.update(img);

        win.set_image(img);
        win.clear_overlay();
        win.add_overlay(tracker.get_position());

        cout << "hit enter to process next frame" << endl;
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
}
```

and with an uglier opencv 2..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "dlib/image_processing.h"
#include "dlib/gui_widgets.h"
#include "dlib/image_io.h"
#include "dlib/dir_nav.h"
#include <dlib/opencv/cv_image.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    CvCapture* camera = cvCaptureFromFile(argv[1]);

    if (camera==NULL)
        printf("camera is null\n");
    else
        printf("camera is not null\n");

    cvNamedWindow("CvCapture");
    while (cvWaitKey(1000)!=atoi("q")) {
        double t1 = (double)cvGetTickCount();
        IplImage *img = cvQueryFrame(camera);

        cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(140, 150, 340, 150));

        IplImage *img1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), img->depth, img->nChannels);
        cvCopy(img, img1, NULL);
        cvResetImageROI(img);

        cvShowImage("ROI",img1);

        cvCvtColor(img1, img1, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        cv_image<unsigned char> img2(img1);
        correlation_tracker tracker;
        tracker.start_track(img2, centered_rect(point(120,100), 80, 150));

        image_window win;
        tracker.update(img2);

        win.set_image(img2);
        win.clear_overlay();
        win.add_overlay(tracker.get_position());

        cout << "hit enter to process next frame" << endl;
        cin.get();

        double t2=(double)cvGetTickCount();
        printf("time: %gms  fps: %.2g\n",(t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.), 1000./((t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.)));
        cvShowImage("CvCapture",img1);
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
}
```

As you see the error came exactly from what I told you before.

Comment: thanks for the answer but again showing the same error

Comment: @JaySingh Did you do this for all dlib functions?

Comment: @JaySingh Did this fix your problem?

Comment: yeah, thanks it helps me a lot but i edited my code as per my need and now it is working but tracking the objects as i updated the question, so if you have any clue than comment.

Comment: @JaySingh The problem you're having now is not related to this question. Please create a new one with the input you're using and a full example.